# Shiny dropdown for list of R ouput images

Tags: r, analytics, shiny, shiny-server

I am trying to display the plot images produced by R on Shiny. My output images are in App-1\www.

Using mainpanel, I am able to display the images one by one. Is it possible to use dropdown and call the images from shiny?

Any suggestion?

Regards,
Raj

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a hack to me, but it works.  I also would like to know if this would work using:

```
mainPanel(
  img(src="nestler_test.jpg", height = 700, width = 00)
)
```

Also apologies for the formatting here....

ui.R

library(shiny)

## Define UI

shinyUI(fluidPage(

# Application title
  titlePanel("The Example"),

# Sidebar with a slider input for the number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("stage", "example text:", 
                  choices = c("stage1", "2", "3"))
    ),

```
# Show a plot of the generated distribution
mainPanel(
  plotOutput("distPlot")
)
```

)
))

server.R

library(jpeg)

## Define server logic

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

```
if (input$stage=="stage1") {
  img=readJPEG('1st_test.jpg')
} else if (input$stage=='2') {
  img=readJPEG('2nd_test.jpg')
}
plot(c(100, 250), c(300, 550), type='n', ylab='',xlab='', xaxt='n', yaxt='n', frame.plot=F)
rasterImage(img, 100, 300, 250, 550)
```

})
})